# How Can Change Input Value When date Is select

Tags: jquery, datepicker

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker8'>
  <input type='text' class="form-control" id="dateOfDeparture" name="dateOfDeparture" value="" />
  <span class="input-group-addon  ">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
  </span>
</div>
<script>
  $('#dateOfDeparture').change(function(e) {
    var valuefirstone = $(this).val(); //use jquery built in functions
    alert(valuefirstone);
  });
</scipt>
```

Comment: What do you want to change it to? and what is not working for you?

Comment: Fix the `</scipt>` typo at the end of your HTML and the code works fine. Some description of what you're attempting to achieve here would be useful too, as there's no date to be 'selected'. You have a plain textbox only.

Comment: What  you are trying to achieve. Here you are picking the value of a text field on change and you are asking help on date. May be changing <input type='date'> may solve your problem (Remember to fix the spelling mistake in 'script' closing tag). If you are in a different situation try to explain what's the issue you are facing actually.